# How many hours should a baby sleep in a day?

Tags: sleep, newborn

Recently, I noticed that my 2-month-old baby sleeps almost all day, including naps (maybe 3-5 hours awake). Should I do anything about this? Should I wake him up or, is it normal?

Comment: How old is the baby? Newborns sleep way more than infants who sleep way more than toddlers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This awesome chart](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11GHo4keUb2TVJUlSL1kD6HQcEgaNFBmzoQoOzcpcyas/edit?hl=en&authkey=CPXE1bsO&pli=1#) takes data from books like [Healthy Sleep Habits, Happy Child](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0449004023) and the experience of the members on the [forum](http://community.babycenter.com/groups/a199215/teaching_your_baby_and_toddler_to_sleep) who developed it.  The totals on that chart are generally much greater than those listed by Dr. Ferber in his [Solve Your Child's Sleep Problems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0743201639), but consistent with other sleep books.

Your child's total wake time sounds normal and, more importantly, *healthy*.  Babies really need sleep to grow and process their experiences.  The wake time will dramatically increase over the next few months.