# Sleeping duration for a toddler

Tags: toddler, sleep

My 15-month old has 2 long sleeps during the day. From 10am to 12 or 1pm and the second sleep from 3.30pm to 6pm.

I have read around that at this age he should be sleeping around 2 hrs during the day, which means my little one is sleeping up to 3x more!

Is this bad? Should we wake him up? Anyone with similar experience?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Consult this answer](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/5356/6061). There's a [great chart](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11GHo4keUb2TVJUlSL1kD6HQcEgaNFBmzoQoOzcpcyas/edit?hl=en&authkey=CPXE1bsO&pli=1#) linked which contains information about suggested sleep patterns for children of different ages.

Remember that each child is different. If he is healthy and you are comfortable with his sleep pattern, perhaps there is no need to change anything.

I'd consider waking him up earlier, his nap should be finished by 4 PM so that he can more easily fall sleep in the evening. He has trouble with that, hasn't he?

Comment: Thanks heaps for the chart. It was a great reference. He doesn't have much trouble to get into sleep. My concern was more about how long he is sleeping. I though having two naps of 2 hours each was too long.

Answer (score 3):

**Don't worry about it**.  Toddler sleep patterns vary widely, and if he's sleeping OK during the night plus happy when he's awake, all is good.

However, I have a sneaky suspicion that waking up at 6pm means he's still up and bouncing away late into the night?  If yes, for your own sanity, you might try your luck at keeping him up in the morning and merging the two naps into one longer post-lunch nap, which is the usual pattern expected by most child care places etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. He usually sleeps at 9pm. We are okay with his current schedule as he can have a nice dinner with us without being too tired. The 6pm range is when he has starts the nap around 4pm.